# How to change the property of a class in JavaScript file on onclick event of some select element?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-events

```
$.widget('ui.spinner', {
options: {
    min: 0,
    max: null,
    allowNull: false,
    
    group: '',
    point: '.',
    prefix: '',
    suffix: '',
    places: null,
```

I have a `ui.spinner.js` file.

I have a spinner on my jsp whose by default min property is set as above,
but on change of a list value, I want to enable entering negative values also for a spinner. How do I do this on `onclick` event of following option?

```
<select autocomplete="off">
  <option value="promotional" selected="selected" id="promotional">Absolute</option>
  <option value="consistent" id="consistent" onclick="changeSpinnerValues();">Relative to WAMP</option>
</select>
```

The spinners are as follows:

```
 <td><label for="st"><strong>WAMP</strong></label>
   <input type="text" id="Spinner" class="spinner" value="0" name="ST_CAPTURE" />
 </td>
 <td><label for="lt"><strong>WAMP</strong></label>
   <input type="text" id="Spinner" class="spinner" value="0" name="LT_CAPTURE" />
 </td>
```

How would I implement `changeSpinnerValues()` function and set the property `min= null;` inside?

Answer (score 0):

First add an id to the select like this:

```
<select id="changer">
    <option value="promotional" selected="selected" id="promotional">Absolute</option>
    <option value="consistent" id="consistent">Relative to WAMP</option>
</select>
```

Then use this js to call your function (onChange not onClick).

```
$('#changer').on('change', function() {
             if($(this).val() == 'consistent') {
                 changeSpinnerValues();
             }
         })
```